# How to set meta robots

Tags: magento-1.9, robots.txt, meta

I want to change my `Magento 1` site so that all of the products pages are **Noindex, follow**.

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: Did @vmp answer worked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your xml file

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```